# How to create a button that adds a new widget every time I click it with streamlit?

Tags: python, widget, streamlit

I have a button called "Add", I would like to let the user create a new selectbox widget every time he clicks it so that if the user decides to press the "Add" button 10 times, 10 selectboxes will be created.
this is the button:

```
        engine.add_clicked  = st.button("Add",on_click = add_callback,help="Add a new test", key="Add", args=(engine, tests_body_container,))
```

this is the on_click function:

```
def add_callback(engine, container):
      with container:
            st.selectbox("options?", ("a", "b", "c"))
```

The problem is that it only works once, it adds one selectbox and then nothing else happens.
[image: image of the streamlit page]

I found a solution that uses session states but I haven't managed to make it work.
The solution I found:
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/adding-widgets-with-button/39953/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this piece of code can help.

Basically you need to add the key you want to the session before using them.
Secondly update the session number in the callback.

```py
import streamlit as st


if 'selectbox_count' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.selectbox_count = 0

def add_callback():
    st.session_state.selectbox_count += 1

    
engine = st.empty()  # Assuming engine is a Streamlit container
add_clicked = engine.button("Add", on_click=add_callback, help="Add a new test", key="Add")

for i in range(st.session_state.selectbox_count):
    st.selectbox(f"Options {i + 1}:", ("a", "b", "c"))
```

Comment: It worked Thank you. The only drawback is that for some reason after Ichoose a second option (in the second droplist) the screen droplists become grey until I press the Add button again.